# Is it possible to set group separator of decimal number in oracle for every session?

Tags: sql, oracle

To alter group separator of decimal number in oracle I use

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';
```

But `ALTER SESSION` means that this will for only for current connection. I've tried only `SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';` but got no effect and `ALTER SYSTEM` also didn't work
So the question is: how to set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS for every session?

Thanks.

Comment: The NLS parms are set from your environment (via the Locale if coming from Java I think), so setting up the client environment properly would be the ideal solution. You could potentially force it with a logon trigger, but that might be overkill. Why is the setting causing you an issue - just in format masks?

Comment: Yes. I'm making benchmarking and I need to insert a lot of data in MySQL an Oracle. Both have different group separator of decimal number s and data that I'm inserting is adapted to MySQL

Comment: In your inserts, are you specifying a format mask, or letting it default? (And if the latter, can you set a mask - in which case you can hard-code the `.` or `,`, instead of using `D` and `G`, which is what the default will effectively do I think). [See the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#sthref376).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach probably depends on how you're inserting your data - whether through SQL*Plus insert statements, SQL*Loader, external tables, or something else.

If you are working in SQL*Plus then you can issue the `alter session` command automatically on login, for yourself only with a [user profile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#sthref92), or with a [site profile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#i1133044).

If you're doing lots of individual insert statements and are using `to_number` already, then there's a [third parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions211.htm#sthref1689) for that which lets you set NLS parameters on a per-command basis. That sounds like a painful way to do 'insert a lot data' though, and amending existing statements might not be too much fun as you'd have to also add the format mask, if there isn't one present.

Alternatively, you can set NLS parameters in your environment; e.g. you can set an NLS_LANG that has the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` setting you want. This is probably preferable overall, and will apply if you're using SQL*Loader to load your data; though I suspect you aren't, and you could use `to_number` in the control file anyway.

Some clients have other ways of setting that; SQL Developer has a Database->NLS section in its preferences, for example.

Lots more on NLS stuff [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that [NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#i1007759) can be set via your init param file at the instance level. The [following list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#g1012703) shows what is modifiable at what level.

Comment: `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` can be set at the instance level.  But as with most of the NLS parameters, the client's settings take precedence over the server's settings.  So setting it at the instance level doesn't end up changing any behavior if there is a client process.

Comment: @JustinCave true, but you're assuming the client process is actually setting this NLS env variable to override this default, no? (setenv ...)

Comment: The client process will always configure a NLS environment.  Exactly how that happens, whether it's based on an explicit setting on the client or the client's `NLS_LANG` or the client JVM's Locale or something else will depend on the client application.  But it will always set up a NLS environment.

Comment: @Justin Cave I agree, but that leads to the question, why is there an instance-level setting at all? When does it have any affect on anything? (Possibly a separate question for [dba.se]...)

Comment: @AlexPoole - I believe that it used to be used in cases where there was no client process (i.e. a job scheduled via `DBMS_JOB`) but now even the job carries NLS information to set up its environment.  I don't think there is anything that actually uses instance-level settings like this any longer.

Comment: @JustinCave I wasn't aware that all clients setup all NLS environment variables.  Not saying you're wrong, just seems not right (even with simple client like sqlplus?).  Don't have access to verify this at moment tho.